# Media library upload hook

Tags: attachments, media-library

I would like to create a function that fires when a file is uploaded to media library to automatically assign multiple categories. So I created this code as proof of concept, but it is not assigning a category:

```
function execute_on_add_attachment_event($post_ID){
    $uploadCategory = array(8);
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $uploadCategory, 'category' );
}
// add the action
add_action( "add_attachment", "execute_on_add_attachment_event" , 10, 1);
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I should have been using `attachment_id`. That works consistently.

I've updated the code below, this version works. I now use $attachment_id rather than $post_id as I originally did:

```php
add_action( "add_attachment", "execute_on_add_attachment_event", 10, 1)
function execute_on_add_attachment_event($attachment_id){
    $uploadCategory = array(8);
    wp_set_object_terms( $attachment_id, $uploadCategory, 'category' );
}
```

Comment: can you edit this answer to explain? I tried to update your answer and wanted to link to `attachment_id` but there is no such hook according to the official WP docs

Comment: I edited the original, so the code in the original post should work.

Comment: can you undo that? It makes the question cryptic and difficult to understand as you're asking about a problem that's been removed, you should edit the answer not the question to include the solution. This isn't a discussion forum and the site has a very particular format, the question should be a question, and the answer goes in the answers. I've tried to extract the answer from your edits, I wasn't sure what to do about the final paragraph as it didn't seem to be a part of either the question or the answer, just a personal comment, _edit: I rolled back your edit to before you added the "fix"_

Comment: Looks like you fixed it, so let me know if there's something else I need to do. In the future, I'll ask other questions separately.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is `media_upload_{$type}` hook.
Here's the documentation for it: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_upload_type/

There's also an easier way to achieve a similar result, by using the filter `wp_handle_upload` which is really straightforward.
Here's the doc about it: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_handle_upload/

If you could provide more details about the result you want to achieve, I'll try my best to help you with some more specific code!